# DB2 user delete at OS level

Tags: db2

If the DB2 uses OS authentication and I delete a DB2 user at the OS level, what will be the impact? Will the DB2 still work fine, and will those privileges that I granted to the user still available after the user is created back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When asking for help with Db2 please mention your Db2-server platform (Z/os , i-series,  Linux/Unix/Windows).  The reason is that the answer be different per platform.  There are also special tags for your question that you can use to indicate the Db2-platform (db2-zos, db2-400, db2-luw).

If you remove the operating system user the impact is that user can no longer connect to the Db2-database(s) . But any GRANTS that were previously created and stored *inside* the database(s) will remain unchanged (unless something REVOKES them), even if they will not be used after all pre-existing connections by that removed-operating-system-user are terminated.

For Db2-Linux/Unix/Windows, if you recreate the user in the operating system the previous GRANTS will reapply only if they are still present inside the database and the user successfully reconnects.  This behaviour may be different on other platforms.

If the Db2-server is configured with special plugins for security, or uses LDAP or other external tooling then the answer can also be different.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I will definitely take care of your comments in the future.